# Copy all files to the destination directory in Fake f#make

Tags: f#, f#-fake, f#-fake-4

I want to copy all files in a particular directory to destination directory.
My code is running perfectly but no files are being copied to the destination folder .

I have tried two approaches but no luck :(
Here is my code:

### Approach 1:

```
#r @"packages\FAKE\tools\FakeLib.dll"

open Fake
let buildDir = "D:/MyDir/build/"
let testDir  = "D:/MyDir/test/"

let sourceDir = "D:/Files"

// Targets
Target "Clean" (fun _ ->
CleanDirs [buildDir; testDir]
)

Target "BuildSetup" (fun _ ->
    !!(sourceDir + "\**\*.txt")
|> Copy testDir)

"Clean"
  ==>"BuildSetup"

RunTargetOrDefault "BuildSetup"
```

### Approach 2 :

```
#r @"packages\FAKE\tools\FakeLib.dll"
open Fake
let buildDir = "D:/MyDir/build/"
let testDir  = "D:/MyDir/test/"

let sourceDir = "D:/Files"

// Targets
Target "Clean" (fun _ ->
CleanDirs [buildDir; testDir ;sourceDir]
)

Target "Default" (fun _ ->
trace "Hello World from FAKE"
) 

let additionalFiles = ["D:\Files\new\*.*"]

Target "CopyFiles" (fun _ ->
CopyTo buildDir additionalFiles
)

Target "BuildSetup" (fun _ ->
    !!("D:\Files\new\*.txt")
|> Copy buildDir)


"Clean"
  //==> "Clean"
  //==> "BuildStep"
  ==> "CopyFiles"

RunTargetOrDefault "BuildSetup"
```

this code is being run , but files are not copied to the destination folder .

please tell me root cause of the problem , I am new to fake .

Comment: How is this question related to CMake? Please remove the CMake tag!

Comment: Your indentation is off everywhere. Please show your code exactly as it is, otherwise we'll just chase red herrings.

Comment: I've removed the irrelevant CMake, Rake, and MSBuild tags as this question has nothing to do with those build systems.

Comment: To show your code exactly as it is, as Fyodor Soikin has asked for (and I second that request), you should first paste it into the edit box, then highlight the entire code section and click the `{}` button. This will add four spaces to the left of the entire highlighted section, evenly -- which means there's no need for doing the manual, often-error-prone "type four spaces into each line" thing. That often leads to messed-up indentation like your question has. Just use the `{}` button: that's what it's for, and it's FAR easier than inserting the spaces by hand.

Comment: BTW, your `BuildSetup` target looks like it's correct, as long as you have the right indentation.

Comment: I've downvoted this question, as the indentation problems make it not very useful for anyone else. If you could fix the indentation problems in your question, it would be far more useful and I could then upvote it instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The below is a working example:

```
#r "./packages/FAKE/tools/FakeLib.dll"

open Fake

let source = "C:/test/source"
let additionalFilesDir = "C:/test/additional"
let dest  = "C:/test/dest/"

Target "Clean" (fun _ ->
    CleanDirs [dest]
)

Target "Default" (fun _ ->
    trace "Hello World from FAKE"
)

Target "CopyDirectory" (fun _ ->
    CopyDir (directory dest) source allFiles
)

Target "CopyAdditionalFiles" (fun _ ->
    !!(additionalFilesDir @@ "**/*")
    --(additionalFilesDir @@ "**/*.txt") //exclude '.txt' files
    |> Copy dest

    //copy will NOT fail if directory not existing
    if not <|directoryExists additionalFilesDir then
        traceError ("additionalFilesDir doesn't exist:" + additionalFilesDir)
)


"Clean"
    ==> "CopyDirectory"
    ==> "CopyAdditionalFiles"
    ==> "Default"

RunTargetOrDefault "Default"
```

Comment: Alex , one more thing , if I want to copy all files but not txt files , i.e. i want to exclude txt files , then is this possible ?

Comment: @kshitijAgrawal - It's usually better to open a new question rather than asking that kind of thing in the comments. But the short version is that the `--` operator is for excluding things from a set of files, and it takes the same wildcard strings that the `!!` operator does. You can do `!! (additionalFilesDir @@ "**/*.*") -- "*.txt" |> Copy dest`, suitably indented, and it will do what you need.

Comment: @KMittal - updated the answer to exclude the "txt" files.